# Polynomial proof qustion

Tags: polynomials

A Polynomial $P(x)=x^3 - Lx^2 + Lx - M$ has zeroes $a$, $1/a$ and $b$.

$$a + \frac1a +b = L$$

$$a + ab +\frac ba = L$$

Show that either $M = 1$ or $M = L-1$.

Can somebody "show" this please?

Comment: Welcome to math.stackechange! Please, provide more context (what do you know about polynomial roots, what did you try to solve it, and the like)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that
$$a\cdot \frac 1a\cdot b=M$$
(this follows from $P(x)=(x-a)(x-\frac 1a)(x-b)$.) So $M=b$. Also, you get
$$
a + \frac1a +b = L\\
1 + ab +\frac ba = L
$$
Substracting them:
$$
0=(a+\frac 1a)(1-b)+b-1=(a+\frac 1a-1)(b-1)
$$
Thus, $b=M=1$ or $a+\frac 1a=1$. That is not possible for real $a$, because $a+\frac 1a\geq 2$. If $a$ is allowed to be complex, you get 
$$
L=a + \frac1a +b = L=1+b
$$
so $b=L-1$.

Comment: whats the reason you subtracted them?

Comment: I did that, because then the solution is easy :) otherwise, it would involve (much) more calculations I guess

Comment: so you subtracted L- L and in that subtraction you showed the proof that b = M must be 1 otherwise L -L is not 0 and shows a contradiction?

Comment: yes, that's what I did

Comment: on the right side of the subtraction, how do we know that its not the right factor thats zero instead

Comment: That may happen, and then, $b=1$.